# J2ME game smooth refresh

Tags: java, java-me

I have developed a game in J2ME. Logic is going perfectly. But the problem is that my sprites are not going properly. They appear continuously flashing. I tried to reduce their size but doesn't help much. I also tried to remove sounds and minimize multiplications and divisions with only a little effect.

My refresh rate is once per 30 milliseconds. My images lie between 300 bytes to 1 kb. Any tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On a mobile phone, once every 30 milliseconds is possibly too much. I created a JME game using only 15 FPS and animations looked fine. Obviously it depends on the game but I'd look into reducing the frame rate if I was you. As mentioned by @Ashok double buffering is used to solve these kinds of problems and it probably will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

better implement double buffering manually if u r using canvas or use gamecanvas which has already double buffer implementation